# Improving a subset solution

Tags: java, algorithm, optimization

I have a practice problem where I have a given value and a given array of numbers. I can use any of the values in the given array once to create a sum equal to the given value.

Original, my algorithm would iterate through the array for every possible combination. I later optimized it to check whether the current sum is greater than the value. If it was, stop trying latter combinations as they will all be greater than the value as well.

Out of curiosity, would it be better to calculate all the sums first then sort the sums and do a binary search to find a sum with an equal value? I imagine that making a comparison at every single sum would be considerably slower than to just precalculate the sums and bs the result.

Comment: You're solving the subset sum problem, which is NP-Complete. Try this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem#Pseudo-polynomial_time_dynamic_programming_solution

Comment: Once you find an answer, you can stop looking.  So it would be more efficient to iterate through and check if you have the answer.  Remember that when you say "binary search", you are implicitly assuming that the data will have to be sorted.  That is even more expensive then all the other options.

Comment: Well i briefly mentioned that I would just calculate every combination of sums and sort that sums so a BS would be possible. Was speculating whether that method would be quicker (albeit much more expensive) than just making a comparison for every level.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly?  Are you trying to make it as *efficient* as possible, or as *simple* as possible, or some combination of both?  Trying to micro-optimize code is very challenging, because all methods are not equal.  Because sorting data can be wrapped into a single method called `Arrays.sort`, it obscures the fact that it is an expensive operation in terms of number of operations and comparisons, simply because you don't see the actual loops and comparisons.

Comment: I am just trying to understand the merits of both. Discerning the pros/cons of different approaches/algorithms.

Comment: Are you familiar with Big-Oh notation?  I would recommend doing Big-Oh analysis of each approach with respect to space and time.  That is a good way to get a sense for the efficiency of an algorithm in terms of factors that matter in the long run.  You will probably find that all of your approaches have roughly the same algorithmic complexity, meaning that averaged over a large set of input sets, they have roughly the same efficiency and scale in similar ways with respect to the size of the original array.

Comment: Some cons of building an array of sums is that you need to first create and store a power set of sums and then sort it afterwards. But we can assume we have unimaginable amounts of storage. I guess it would boil down to whether the number of comparisons done during your sort would be on average less than or equal to the number of comparisons done during a brute-force search.

Comment: In a modified version where the values in the array can be summed with the given value (and the remaining elements are eligible to be summed to find a solution), would precalculating the sum then be more efficient since you wouldn only need to calculate sums once and just manipulate the power set

Comment: I think I get what you're saying. If you have the list `[4,5,6,7]`, and you pre-calculated that the first two elements sum to `9`, then you can combine `9` with the remaining elements without repeatedly calculating `4+5`.  That is true, but I can imagine an iterative approach (using recursion) that would do exactly that and still be able to stop early once it found a solution.  Would you care to share your current solution, i.e. via pastebin?  I'm curious how you implemented checking through every combination.

Comment: It seems like while you're busy building your power set, you would have already found your result if a result exists...

Comment: @CoderNinja: If you were going to search for multiple values, say whether all numbers `1-10` can be made as sums from an array, then it would definitely make sense to pre-calculate the power sum.  However, that is a very different scenario than searching for a single value.  Every time you re-run your program with a new input array and new search value, it has to rebuild the powerset array from scratch, which is less efficient than just iterating through and stopping once you've found it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would computing all of the sums, and then searching for a sum that is equal to the desired value be more efficient (in time) than a simple brute-force search?

If we consider the worst case where no such set exists, then the number of add operations that you need to do are equal for both solutions, since you're already computing every sum in your solution, and the brute-force search would eventually try every combination.

Would the number of comparisons made in your solution be less than or equal to the number of comparisons done using brute-force? Yes. You definitely don't need to first compute all the sums and THEN sort the result: you can simply build a sorted set while you're doing all your computations. Brute-forcing would end up doing as many comparisons as there are combinations, but building a sorted collection of all sums and then doing a binary search for a matching value should not be exponential.

But then again, you probably would have already found a solution while you're building your power set, so I'm not sure how different it is compared to simple brute-force. It just looks like a more expensive brute-force since now you've got to deal with storing all those sums and other intermediary computations if you choose to do so.